# Проблема в работе gem CarrierWave

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Для проекта на `Rails 4.2.5` был установлен `gem CarrierWave`.
При создании нового объекта и загрузки изображения ошибок не возникало

После установки `gem RailsAdmin` при попытке создать новый объект с картинкой возникает следующая ошибка:

```
ArgumentError in RailsAdmin::MainController#new
wrong number of arguments (1 for 0)

Extracted source (around line #115):

113  #
114  # This method is not thread-safe.
115  def quietly
116    ActiveSupport::Deprecation.warn(
117      "`#quietly` is deprecated and will be removed in the next release."
118    ) #not thread-safe
```

[image: Скриншот]

Подскажите в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Гемы явно подрались за коллбэки у модели, в результате чего кто-то вызвал `quietly`, не принимающий аргументов, с одним аргументом. Возьмите отладчик, доберитесь до [того кто это сделал](https://github.com/carrierwaveuploader/carrierwave/blob/v0.10.0/lib/carrierwave/uploader/processing.rb#L84) и... ну, дальше в зависимости от того, что найдёте.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема решается следующим способом:

В файле `image_uploader.rb`(имя файла взято с моего проекта, у вас оно может быть другим), находим следующие строки и комментируем их:

```
# Create different versions of your uploaded files:
  # version :thumb do
  #   process :resize_to_fit => [50, 50]
  # end
  #
```

Comment: То есть, просто выкидываем возможность создавать превьюшки? Странное решение.

Comment: могу ошибаться но на сколько я понял их следует завать в rails_admin.rb там есть следующий комментарий в коде:  field :asset do thumb_method :large # set a method available to your asset (defaults to :thumb, :thumbnail or '100x100>' for Dragonfly).